# Request.RawUrl vs. Request.Url

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between `Request.RawUrl` and `Request.Url` in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From MSDN:

> The raw URL is defined as the part of
>   the URL following the domain
>   information. In the URL string
>   `http://www.contoso.com/articles/recent.aspx`,
>   the raw URL is
>   *`/articles/recent.aspx`*.

This means, you can use `rawurl` and do not have to care about through which address the server was called (for instance `http://yourserver/` or `http://yourserver.yourdomain.com/` if you have multiple interfaces.)

However, the `URL` property of an `HTTPRequest` object returns a `System.URI` object, which also contains server name.

Comment: This explanation incorrectly implies that `Request.RawUrl` is just syntactic sugar for `Request.Url.LocalPath`.

Comment: @Brian it might be helpful to explain how it's not just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @MalRoss: They can be different paths entirely during path rewriting (e.g., 404 handlers).  See [British Developer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20381367/18192)

Comment: One issue I can't resolve is how to get the default url.  For example, I'll get just a "/" for localhost:53188, but what I want is localhost:53188/Home/Index

Answer (score 70):

No one seems to have mentioned that it shows the Raw URL actually received by IIS, before any manipulation may have happened sending it around IIS or your file system with URL rewriting for example.

Say you have set an error page at `/error` in an MVC app and you set your webconfig to replace error pages with your custom error page at that location. In this way when getting an error at `/faultypage`, the user will get the page at `/error` but the url in your browser's address bar will still say `www.mysite.com/faultypage`—this is a transfer, or a rewrite.

Now on your error controller if you are to take a peek at `Request.Url`, it will be something like `www.mysite.com/error` and `Request.RawUrl` would say (more usefully?) `/faultypage` which is the user's actual request not the page that is currently being executed.

Answer (score 18):

`Request.RawUrl` is very similar to `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` *except* that `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` includes the [Default Document](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument) if one was used whereas `Request.RawUrl` does not.  From my experience, this is true for [ASP.Net 4.0 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980401/net-4-0-request-rawurl-not-set-to-default-aspx-at-application-root).

Answer (score 6):

The [HttpRequest.RawUrl Property documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.rawurl?view=netframework-4.7.2) describes the property value as:

> The raw URL is defined as the part of the URL following the domain information. In the URL string `http://www.contoso.com/articles/recent.aspx`, the raw URL is `/articles/recent.aspx`. The raw URL includes the query string, if present.

The [HttpRequest.Url Property documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.url?view=netframework-4.7.2) describes the property value as:

> A [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.7.2) object that contains the URL of the current request.

See the [Uri class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.7.2) for its properties.

Answer (score 5):

Request.RawUrl returns a string, it's everything after the domain information for the current url.

Eg, for: [Request.RawUrl vs. Request.Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019735/request-rawurl-vs-request-url)

Request.RawUrl would be /questions/2019735/request-rawurl-vs-request-url

Request.Url returns a Uri object, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_members.aspx