# How to set form action attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have just updated my ASP.NET application from .NET 3.5 to 4.0. One of the [breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770154) is the form action attribute is empty when navigating to the root folder, instead of previously automatically picking up default.aspx.

Seting the action attribute in markup or in the code-behind doesn't work as the action attribute is still empty when the page is rendered.

Markup: <form id="MyForm" runat="server" action="default.aspx">

Code: Me.Page.Form.Action = "default.aspx"

Using jQuery to add the action on the ready event does work.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#MyForm').attr("action","default.aspx");
        });
```

Is there another solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery to change form action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451600/jquery-to-change-form-action)

Answer (score 0):

You should try : 
    $('form').get('MyForm').setAttribute('action', 'default.aspx');