# How to log the Event URL field in Kentico for 404 pages in Azure Application Inisghts?

Tags: azure, kentico, azure-application-insights

I would like to log the "Event URL" field in Kentico Portal logs to Azure Application Insights for 404 requests. Since I changed my custom page for 404 errors in Kentico Portal I only get "PortalTemplate.apsx" for the url field in the requests table in AppInsights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already have this as a [recommendation on the GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/177) - use `RawUrl` instead of `Request.Url`.

As explained here RawUrl better suites cases when the request was redirected to the custom error page: [Request.RawUrl vs. Request.Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019735/request-rawurl-vs-request-url)

Please upvote the issue on GitHub. As a workaround now you can replace [OperationNameTelemetryInitializer](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/master/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/OperationNameTelemetryInitializer.cs) in `ApplicaitonInsights.config` to your own implementation of it that uses `RawUrl` instead of the `Url`.

Comment: Do you know what I should change in OperationNameTelemetryInitializer?

Comment: @purplePanda in the [line](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/75373e57dcf8d646c54ee188461c373f2cc98939/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/Implementation/RequestTrackingExtensions.cs#L49) `string name = request.UnvalidatedGetPath();` use the path from `RawUrl`. Also set the `RequestTelemetry.Url` to `RawUrl` value in `OperationNameTelemetryInitializer` itself or create a new initializer for it.