# Get URL from address bar in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, code-behind

Am working in asp.net and had to rewrite some urls rewriting is working fine here is an example I had to change URL mywebsite.com/search.aspx?cat=1 to mywebsite.com/search/cameras and it's working fine now I have to change page meta tags and when I try to get url by using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery
```

am getting `search.aspx?cat=1`

while I want here is address written in address bar which is search/cameras
if it's not possible than is there any way to set meta tags for specific pages?
here is code for url rewrite

```
m_boolIsCustomPage = true;

m_strPageBaseUrl = "search.aspx";
if (m_intIDSearch > -1)
{
    l_strQueryContents = m_intIDSearch.ToString();
    m_intIDSearch = -1;
}
else
{
    l_strQueryContents = "-1";
    m_intIDSearch = -1;
}
```

Comment: Did you try this - `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` ?

Comment: Yes have tried this one but it's not giving me address written in addressbar while giving search.aspx?cat=1

Comment: Please show the code that _rewrite some urls_

Comment: have edited my question after setting querycontents from code I manually read them from code behind on page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl`

As received by IIS prior to any manipulation.
[Request.RawUrl vs. Request.Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019735/request-rawurl-vs-request-url)