# returnUrl drops second querystring parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 5.  The problem is that after SSO redirects back to the app after authentication the login method returnUrl drops the applicaitonId querystring parameter. Please help!

Here is the flow.

1. The app redirects unauthorized users to a login method, preserving the original request in the returnUrl.

   The original request is

   ```
    http://localhost:25451/shared/download?documentGroup=133&applicationId=3153
   ```

   the returnUrl is

   ```
    /shared/download?documentGroup=133&applicationId=3153
   ```
2. The app redirects to a SSO CAS server, sending along the HttpUtility.Encode returnUrl as a parameter along with login Url both part of the service parameters.

   ```
    https://{redacted}/cas/login?service=http://localhost:25451/account/login%3freturnUrl%3d%2fshared%2fdownload%3fdocumentGroup%3d133%26applicationId%3d3153
   ```
3. After authentication, the CAS server appends the authorized ticket and redirects back to the service URL.  This is what fiddler shows.

   ```
    http://localhost:25451/account/login?returnUrl=/shared/download?documentGroup=133&applicationId=3153&ticket={redacted}
   ```
4. Here is the issue.  The returnuRL in the login method is simply

   ```
   /shared/download?documentGroup=133.
   ```

   The returnUrl no longer has the applicationId.

Interestingly enough, the line works just fine.

```
var ticket = Request.QueryString.Get("ticket");
```

I have tried to encode the whole serviceUrl and tried to encode just the returnUrl(see below) but I get the same missing ApplicationId issue.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    var ticket = Request.QueryString.Get("ticket");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticket))
    {
        //verify the ticket...
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    var serviceUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host + (Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + Request.Url.Port) + "/account/login" + "?returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl);
    var authenCasUrl = string.Format("{0}login?service={1}", "https://{redacted}/", serviceUrl);
    return Redirect(authenCasUrl);
}
```

Comment: if you invert the two parameters documentGroup=133&applicationId=3153 => applicationId=3153&documentGroup=133 is always the first parameter persisted ?

Comment: Thanks for the response @B.Lec.  Switching the variables dropped the documentId.  So it seems that 2nd parameter is dropped regardless of the order.

Comment: I have no clue on what is appenning, as a workaround you should try to use only 1 "state" parameter and serialize all you need in its value as a base64 encoded json

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls Flurl supports a url.combine that handels all the url combining magic.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with asp or SSO, but you may need to **also** `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` the value of the `serviceUrl` variable?

```cs
var authenCasUrl = string.Format("{0}login?service={1}", "https://{redacted}/", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(serviceUrl));
```

Since the service parameter is decoded by the CAS once, and then the value of returnUrl gets decoded by your server.

```cs
var returnUrl = "/shared/download?documentGroup=133&applicationId=3153";
var serviceUrl = "http://localhost:25451/account/login?returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl);
var casUrl = "https://{redacted}/cas/login?service=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(serviceUrl);
```

Which gives:

```
serviceUrl = http://localhost:25451/account/login?returnUrl=%2Fshared%2Fdownload%3FdocumentGroup%3D133%26applicationId%3D3153
casUrl     = https://{redacted}/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A25451%2Faccount%2Flogin%3FreturnUrl%3D%252Fshared%252Fdownload%253FdocumentGroup%253D133%2526applicationId%253D3153
```

---

###### Explanation attempt:

- You make a HTTP request to the CAS server. It's implementation splits the query parameters and decodes each value (and possibly key). One of which is the service parameter and is now (after decoding) a valid URL.
- The CAS server makes a HTTP request with the URL from the service parameter (to your server) with the ticket appended.
- You split the query parameters and decode each value (and possibly key).

If you only encoded the `returnUrl` once, your `serviceUrl` will look like what you showed in your third point:

```
http://localhost:25451/account/login?returnUrl=/shared/download?documentGroup=133&applicationId=3153&ticket={redacted}
```

How does the algorithm splitting the query string differentiate between a `?` or `&` in the `serviceUrl` and the ones in the `returnUrl`?
How should it know that `ticket` does not belong to the `returnUrl`?

As you can see in my code above, you are not encoding the `returnUrl` twice.
You are putting one URL in the parameters of another URL and then you put that URL in the parameters of a third URL.

You need to call `UrlEncode` for each value (and possibly key) when you put together a query. It does not matter whether that value is a URL, JSON, or arbitrary user input.

Comment: This works and I will award the bounty.  Before I accept it as the answer, I would like to know why does it work?  Does not make sense to double encode the returnUrl.

Comment: can you change your code from HttpUtility.Encode to HttpUtility.UrlEncode?  Thank you!

Comment: @salli I've added an explanation as requested and changed `Encode` to `UrlEncode`. I hope this is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Since this site will be actually called by your URL, I don't think they just throw away parts of it.
Lets try something here since I have encountered a similar problem with parameter in url strings in combination with asp.NET.

First, lets get the unedited URL from your Request:

```
string UneditedUrl = Request.RawUrl;
```

Since we are not needing anything before the ? mark, we shorten it a little bit:

```
string QueryString = (UneditedUrl.IndexOf('?') < UneditedUrl.Length - 1) ? UneditedUrl.Substring(UneditedUrl.IndexOf('?') + 1) : String.Empty;
```

This line also includes the possibility on neither having a ? mark or parameters and will return an empty string if so. Just for good measure, we don't want any exceptions here. Here you can check `QueryString` if it has both or more of your parameters you entered.

If there are not complete here, its not your code at fault. Something will already work on your URL before you do, probably your host then. Maybe check the settings of your IIS.

---

If your parameters are correctly in the edited `QueryString`, you can continue getting them by following this:

I learned that there is a way to let your framework do the job of parsing parameters into name/value collections. So lets give it a go:

```
NameValueCollection ParaCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(QueryString);
```

You can now check you params and their values by either using an index like `ParaCollection[0]` or `ParaCollection["documentGroup"]`.

EDIT:
I've found the question which brought me to the conclusion of using `Request.RawUrl`. Since this may not be the answer, it will maybe help a little bit more to understand that `Request.RawUrl` is the actual URL the user called and not the one the server executes: [RawURL vs URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019735/request-rawurl-vs-request-url)

Comment: This is a good alternative solution.  However, the solution provided by @dmtweigt returns the applicationId.

Comment: @salli interesting, is the applicationId in QueryString already missing?